# Which version of Amazon Corretto JDK supports TLS 1.3?

Tags: java-8, corretto

What version of Corretto JDK supports TLS 1.3? It seems that Corretto JDK 8 does not support tls 1.3. Is there any way to support TLS 1.3 in Corretto 1.8.0_202 ?

Answer (score 2):

Anyway finally,

Amazon Corretto 8u272, 11.0.9, 15.0.1 quarterly updates are now available
Posted On: Oct 26, 2020

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-corretto-quarterly-updates-now-available/

Today Amazon announced quarterly updates for Amazon Corretto 8, Amazon Corretto 11, and Amazon Corretto 15. This release also includes Corretto 8 support for **TLS1.3**, Corretto 11 ARM64 updates and Corretto 11 general availability of the Shenandoah GC (Garbage Collector). Amazon Corretto is a no-cost, multi-platform, production-ready distribution of OpenJDK.